# Function with input variables returns -nan and -inf

Tags: c

So I need a lot of different table files and decided to try and create them with C. The code does in general what it's supposed to but I get -nan and -inf in the 2. and 3. cloumns (4-7 work fine).

4.0000000000e-02     -nan     -inf
4.2000000000e-02     -nan     -inf
4.4000000000e-02     -nan     -inf

The values in these columns come from functions with input variables, so I probably made a mistake defining them. Since this is the first thing I ever did in C I'm sure I made a very dumb mistake so thanks in advance.

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main()
{

    FILE    *fout;
    double e,o,k,c,r;

    printf("Define the relative dielectric constant:\n");
    scanf("%d",&e);

    printf("Define the cutoff radius:\n");
    scanf("%d",&o);

    k = (78-e)/(pow(o,3)*(156+e));
    c = (1/o)+k*pow(o,2);

    fout = fopen("table_XX_XX.xvg", "w");
    fprintf(fout, "#\n# Tabulated Potential for AA-AA Interactions\n#\n");

    for (r=0; r<=3; r+=0.002) {

        double f = ((1/r)+k*pow(r,2)-c)/e;
        double fprime = (pow(r,-2)-2*k*r)/e;

        double g = -1/(pow(r,6));
        double gprime = -6/(pow(r,7));

        double h = 1/(pow(r,12));
        double hprime = 12/(pow(r,13));

        /* print output */
        if (r<0.04) {
            fprintf(fout, "%12.10e   %12.10e %12.10e   %12.10e %12.10e   %12.10e %12.10e\n", r,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
        } else {
            fprintf(fout, "%12.10e   %12.10e %12.10e   %12.10e %12.10e   %12.10e %12.10e\n", r,f,fprime,g,gprime,h,hprime);
        }
    }

    fclose(fout);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: When `r==0` what's the value of `1/r` ?  Also check the valid domain ranges for `std::pow`  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow  Use your debugger, step though and watch the results.

Comment: `double e` and `scanf("%d",&e);`?  Wrong format.  `%d` is for `int`.  That's undefined behavior.

Comment: Using floating point for loop induction variables is usually an indication of "doing it wrong".

Comment: Your declaration of `main` is wrong in both C and C++ (also decide on one of the two)

Comment: "%lf" for reading a double

Comment: `main` *always* returns `int`.

Comment: Why are you using `FILE*` and `printf()` in C++? Or maybe you wanted to tag your question as C only?

Comment: Changing "%d" to "%lf" did it. Thank you

Comment: You should not use `for (r=0; r<=3; r+=0.002)` to iterate through floating-point values unless you fully understand floating-point arithmetic and know the values will work in that specific case. For example, if the increment were `.02` instead of `.002`, that loop would end with `r` being about 2.98; it would not execute an iteration where `r` was 3. Instead, iterate with an integer counter and scale it: `for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i += 2) { r = i * .001; … }`.

Comment: I am curious, how did using a `%d` format specifier address the `1/0` condition in the for loop shown at bottom of post?  This would still produce a `+ inf` condition.

Comment: @ ryyker: It still does produce +inf for r=0 but I assign it zero, which is appropriate for what I need the tables for. I'm only interested in f, g and h for r>0.04 but I still need r to go from 0.0 to 3.0. My problem was that my code didn't work for any given value.

Answer (score 2):

As *[cited here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Infinity-and-NaN.html)*, *[and here](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FLP04-C.+Check+floating-point+inputs+for+exceptional+values)*, `+/-inf, or nan are generated by such operations as:

1/0 = ∞
log (0) = -∞
sqrt (-1) = NaN

When using ratios, and or exponential operations, checks should always be included in your code to exclude exceptional values from being processed by such operations.

Walk through the sections of your code where `inf` or `nan` values are being generated, identify how the ratios or functions might be assigned incorrect values, and address them. (eg. by surrounding that section of code with a test for illegal value, and set a condition to bypass the operation when such a value is present.)

Keep in mind the difference between accepting and using the values of `+/-∞` and `NaN`.

When using them, the basic operations and math functions all accept `∞` and `NaN` and produce sensible output.  However, ∞ propagates through calculations as one would expect: for example, `2 + ∞` = `∞;`, `4/∞;` = `0`, `atan (∞)` = `pi;/2`.

`NaN`, on the other hand, infects any calculation that involves it. Unless the calculation would produce the same result no matter what real value replaced `NaN`, the result is `NaN`. (adapted from 2nd link above).

Comment: I thought I avoided something like this with the if statement at the end.

Comment: In case you missed OP’s comment above, their error was using `%d` in scanf, resulting in the `double` `o` and `e` not being assigned the intended values, and they report that, with that changed to `%f`, the code is operating as desired.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - Thanks for pointing this out.  I find it interesting that for `r == 0` that ` `((1/r)+k*pow(r,2)-c)/e;` would not product `+inf`.  How does a format specifier fix that?  OP might be operating with a code base not exactly equal to what is presented above.

Comment: @ryyker: It produces ∞, but the OP seems satisfied with that so far. The object it is assigned to, `f`, is not used in any further calculations in the code shown. As the program develops, it might be used, but ∞ is not an error in floating-point. It may get used in some way that makes sense, such as in the denominator of some expression, so the expression evaluates to zero.

Comment: As mentioned above I don't need a value for f(r=0), but thanks for your  explanation on +/-inf, and nan. I'm sure your suggestions will be very helpful when I encounter other functions where I need to exclude specific values.